# Codeception see and dontSee both fail

Tags: codeception

I'm using the Selenium2 module for acceptance tests

My acceptance.suite.yml contains

```
class_name: WebGuy
modules:
    enabled: [Selenium2]
    config:
        Selenium2:
            url: 'http://localhost/'
            browser: firefox
            capabilities:
                unexpectedAlertBehaviour: 'accept'
```

In my test file I've tried both of the following and they both fail

```
$I->seeElement('.menu .subMenu');

$I->dontSeeElement('.menu .subMenu');
```

I would expect the dontSee assertion to pass as the sub menu is hidden by default

The error I get is

Guy unexpectedly managed to see element ".menu .subMenu": Failed asserting that an object is empty.

The beginning of my HTML looks like this

```
<div class="menu">
  <div class="subMenu" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't solved it yet. I had to leave the test out for that project.

Answer (score 0):

Try using XPaths:

```
$I->seeElement("//div[@class='menu']");
```

Comment: I tried using xpaths but both the following two tests both fail

$I->seeElement("//div[@class='subMenu']");

$I->dontSeeElement("//div[@class='subMenu']");

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Codeception: https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/617

Edit: Switching to the WebDriver module instead of Selenium seems to have fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Is disabled your HTML-code `div.menu` by `display:none;`? Perhaps that's the reason.

I think, I have had a similiar problem with the webdriver and the code

`$checkHygienePlans = $I->grabMultiple('.js-my-test-block a');`

The result $checkHygienePlans was an array with empty string and `$I->assertContains('TestSomeThing', $checkHygienePlans);` would fail the test.
The reason was, that the wraping block of the element with class `js-my-test-block` was hidden with CSS **`display: none;`**
After I used codeception to untoggle that block, everything worked fine.